# What does synchronized means in Java

Tags: java

Regarding the difference beween hashMap and hashTable in Java, I read this.

Can anyone help me what does "Synchronized" below means?

“The key difference between the two is that access to the Hashtable is synchronized on the table while access to the HashMap isn't. You can add it, but it isn't there by default.”

Thank you!